# The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Tags: java

I have installed Java 8 on my PC and programs are getting compiled.

When i try to execute it using `cmd` prompt it is showing me the following error:

```
"The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe."
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is there really a folder named `javapath` in your `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java` folder?

Comment: There is on my PC.  I guess this must be a new thing - Not like the good old days of "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin"

Comment: @Adamski Huh? That's odd, I'll have to make note of that. When I read it, it seems redundant or misplaced, like it should be  `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\javapath\Java`. And why not `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\pathtojava`?

Comment: How are you executing it on cmd , please include full command in question

Comment: Sounds like your JRE installation is broken.  Try reinstalling the JRE and/or the Java plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking your PATH environment variable to ensure it includes: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

[image]